# Web scraping using python: urlopen returns HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Tags: python, python-requests, urlopen

I'm trying to download data from Fragantica.com using urlopen but an error occurs ("HTTP Error 403: Forbidden") even after changing the user-agent and adding headers. 
I have tried the code from here as well with no success (http://wolfprojects.altervista.org/changeua.php#problem).

Here is my code:

```
import urllib.request

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_2) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.4 Safari/605.1.15'



url = "https://www.fragrantica.com/perfume/Tom-Ford/Tobacco-Vanille-1825.html"
headers={'User-Agent':user_agent,} 

request=urllib.request.Request(url,None,headers) #The assembled request
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
data = response.read() # The data u need
```

This is the error I encounter: HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to specify more headers, try this:

```
import urllib.request    

url = "https://www.fragrantica.com/perfume/Tom-Ford/Tobacco-Vanille-1825.html"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_2) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.4 Safari/605.1.15',
       'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
       'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
       'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
       'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
       'Connection': 'keep-alive'} 

request=urllib.request.Request(url=url, headers=headers) #The assembled request
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
data = response.read() # The data u need
```